# C Segmentation Fault(Core Dump) can not figure out why

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

***EDIT: I solved the problem of output file(always case sensitive). But the first problem with segmentation fault is still there.***

***EDIT 2: So I ran the gdb and this came up ***

```
      Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
     _IO_new_fclose (fp=0x0) at iofclose.c:54
      54        if (fp->_IO_file_flags & _IO_IS_FILEBUF)
```

***EDIT 3: It shows the error is at fclose(file) on lineCounter mygrep.c:42***

I have a problem with my C program. To give it a little information, for our first assignment we were asked to implement the grep command in UNIX based systems in C. we have the arguments such as **grep [-i] [-o outfile] keyword filename**(to be read).

if **[-i]** is present, the searched keyword will be case insensitive.

if **[-o outfile]** is specified, the result will be written in this file. Otherwise it will be given to screen.

**keyword** is the pattern which we are supposed to search and **filename** is the name of the file which will be read.

Everything was going fine until I tried to implement the **[-o outfile]** section where it checks if it is NULL or not.

Without the presence of **[-o outfile]** the program successfully prints the result on screen (both case insensitive and sensitive) but at the end gives *Segmentation Fault(core dumped)* despite it works.

So for the visualize the problem , it is like this:

EXAMPLE.IN has =

ARduino

retard

ARD

```
    mygrep -i ard example.in
```

This command prints out

```
    ARduino
    retard
    ARD
    Segmentation Fault(core dumped)
```

Same one goes for the case sensitive but it works

```
   mygrep -i ard example.in
   ard
   Segmentation Fault(core dumped)
```

I really couldn't figure out why this happens I am new to C. I usually code in Java.

Here is the main.c method:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <getopt.h>
 #include "mygrep.h"
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
   bool caseSensitive = true;
   char *outfile = NULL;
   int c;

   while((c= getopt(argc,argv,"io:"))!= -1)
   {
     switch(c)
     {
       case 'i' : caseSensitive = false;
                  break;
       case 'o' : outfile = optarg;
                  break;
       default:
                  break;
      }

    }
   char *keyword = argv[optind];
   char *inputfile = argv[optind+1];
   mygrep(inputfile,caseSensitive,keyword,outfile);
 }
```

mygrep.c method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mygrep.h"
static int lineCounter(char filename[])
{
   FILE *file = fopen(filename,"r");
   int lines,c;
   lines = 0;
   if(file)
   {
      while((c = getc(file)) !=EOF)
      {
         if(c == '\n')
         {
           ++lines;
         }
      }
   }
   fclose(file); //** THIS IS THE LINE WHERE DEBUGGER GETS ERROR**
   return lines;
}

int mygrep(char filename[],bool caseSensitive,char pattern[],char outfile[])
{
  char str[100];
  int lines = lineCounter(filename);
  FILE *file = fopen(filename,"r");
  FILE *out;
  int i = 0;
  if (outfile != NULL)
  {
     out = fopen(outfile,"w");
  }

  if(file == NULL)
  {
    perror("Error opening file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while(i<lines)
  {
      if(fgets (str,100, file)!= NULL )
      {
          if(caseSensitive)
          {
              if(strstr(str,pattern) != NULL)
              {
                 if(outfile == NULL)
                 {
                    printf("%s",str);
                 } else
                 {
                     fprintf(out,"%s",str);
                 }
              }
          } else 
          {
              if(strcasestr(str,pattern) != NULL)
              {
                 if(outfile== NULL)
                 {
                    printf("%s",str);
                 } else 
                 {
                      fprintf(out,"%s",str);
                 }
              }
          }
      }
      ++i;
}
fclose(out);
fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you run this with your debugger? The debugger will tell you where exactly the crash happens.

Comment: You should only open the output file once.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I am writing from terminal and still do not know the C debugger. I will check it.

Comment: @Aegean it's great time to start learning it now, it will save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: @tripleee THANKS! I made a conditional statement to check if outfile is not null, then it opens the file once and it worked! So the problem 2 is solved.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I will check some tutorials on it in a minute :)

Comment: @Aegean I don't know which is your platform/IDE/compiler, but if gdb is available, google "gdb tutorial"